# Are there downsides for creating a large VARCHAR value in Redshift?

Tags: sql, ddl, amazon-redshift

The source data keeps throwing values for the field that keep getting bigger and bigger in length. Right now I'm using VARCHAR(200) but I might go for `VARCHAR(400)`. Are there any disadvantages using a large number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean "downside"?  There is a really big downside if you don't make the column big enough -- you can't use it to store the values you want to store there.

As for additional overhead, you don't need to worry about that.  A `varchar()` type basically only takes up the storage needed for the value, plus a small overhead for the length.  Also, "400" is not such a big number, especially when compared to "200".

So, if you need 400 bytes to store the value, change the table to store it.  There may be overhead for changing the length of the value.  I'm not sure if RedShift will feel the need to copy the data because the type changed.  However, the effect on performance should be negligible.

Comment: I just assumed and thought that there would be additional overhead to allocate a varying amount of space for a field

Comment: @simplycoding You assumed correctly.   Having a field too large won't affect storage space but can affect query performance in some cases: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-smallest-column-size.html

Answer (score 12):

> Don’t make it a practice to use the maximum column size for convenience.
>
> Instead, consider the largest values you are likely to store in a VARCHAR column, for example, and size your columns accordingly. Because Amazon Redshift compresses column data very effectively, creating columns much larger than necessary has minimal impact on the size of data tables. During processing for complex queries, however, intermediate query results might need to be stored in temporary tables. Because temporary tables are not compressed, unnecessarily large columns consume excessive memory and temporary disk space, which can affect query performance.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-smallest-column-size.html

Comment: . . That documentation does not make sense.  `VARCHAR()` uses space only for the values being stored, plus a fixed small amount of overhead (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html).  Whether the value is uncompressed or not, RedShift should not be padding varchar values to be longer than their actual length.

Comment: Well the docs are written by the DB maintainers so I guess it's there for a reason. More importantly I've tested it and it _does_ make a difference. If I had to guess, I suspect that the database allocates extra RAM for potentially huge columns during query processing when the columns are "rematerialized" into rows.

Comment: Redshift compresses column data, so over-sized VARCHAR columns should not affect table size. However, unnecessarily large VARCHAR columns can affect query performance: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-smallest-column-size.html